# Passing variables from route group to route functions in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have one installation of Laravel on which I wish to run 3 sites (addon domains). I am using Laravel's route grouping method to grab each domain. However, I need to be able to know which domain I am working with inside of each group. What is the best way to do this? I have the following code:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'domainone.com'), function($domain = 'domainone')
{
    Route::get('/', function($domain) {
         //
    });
});
```

^ Which doesn't work.

The [notes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#sub-domain-routing) suggest using wildcards in the URL, eg.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function($domain) {
         //
    });
});
```

However, I would prefer a different method, as I can't really use this during development on my local server. Is there any way that is more like my first method, in which I can just manually declare a key for each domain?

EDIT: I also then need to pass that domain variable to a controller, which I am also struggling to work out how to do?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT 2**

My problem is that I am not using subdomains, I am using domains; I have 3 separate domains for 3 sister sites that are running on the same installation of Laravel. So I have 3 route groups, one for each domain. Moreover, I don't want to **request** the domain variable using `{domain}.com` each time, I want to **tell** Laravel the domain in each case, then pass that domain as a variable to the appropriate controller within each group. Here is my example code:

```
$domain1 = 'domain1.com';
$domain2 = 'domain2.com';
$domain3 = 'domain3.com';

Route::group(array('domain' => $domain1), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PrimaryController@somefunction1');  // <-- I want to access $domain1 in my controller
});
Route::group(array('domain' => $domain2), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PrimaryController@somefunction2');  // <-- ...and $domain2
});
Route::group(array('domain' => $domain3), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'PrimaryController@somefunction3');  // <-- ...and $domain3
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an option for your first method:

```
$domain = 'domainone';
Route::group(array('domain' => $domain.'.com'), function() use ($domain)
{
    Route::get('/', function() use ($domain) {
         echo "$domain";
    });
});
```

You can pass watever you like to your controllers, via groups too, you just need to add one more level.

```
$subdomain = 'atlanta';
$domain = 'domainone';

Route::group(array('domain' => "$subdomain.$domain.com"), function()
{
    Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.{domain}.com'), function()
    {
        Route::get('testdomain', function($subdomain, $domain) {
            dd("closure: subdomain: $subdomain - domain: $domain");
        });

        Route::get('testdomaincontroller', 'FooController@index');
    });
});
```

By doing this you have to understand that your first two variables passed to your controller action will always be $subdomain and $subdomain. Here's a controller to show it, which you can use to test those routes too:

```
class FooController extends Controller {

    public function index($subdomain, $domain)
    {
        dd("controller: subdomain: $subdomain - domain: $domain");
    }
}
```

You'll have two different routes with this:

```
http://yourdomain.dev/testdomain
http://yourdomain.dev/testdomaincontroller
```

Comment: Sorry, this seems to throw an error: `Missing argument 1 for {closure}()` referring to the line `Route::get('/', function($domain) {`

Comment: You need to do the same on the second one. Edited.

Comment: Great, thanks, Antonio, working now. Just to wrap this up, do you know how I would then pass this variable to a controller, ie if I had `Route::get('/', 'PrimaryController@index');` How would I send the domain variable to this controller function? Thanks.

Comment: To use these in your controller, you just have to place a parameter in your controller method.  `public function controller_method($variable)` will catch and assign the first parameter group's value to a variable called `$variable` within your controller function.

Comment: @James Hi, I am coming back to this problem again... in your example the `Route::get()` part uses a closure with a simple echo. But I want to use `Route::get('/', 'PrimaryController@index');` to send to my controller. In this case, how do I also send the `$domain` variable?

Comment: It's not too tough - I do this in several of the applications I'm using.  I'll post an answer so I can do some code formatting.

Comment: Just added some more examples to show how to pass it to your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this with the following two steps:

First, using the Laravel documentation example, I pull the subdomain down and assign it to {account}.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'), function()
```

From here, any controller you assign to a route *within this group* will have the ability to inject this *{account}* data in to its functions.

Note: you **can't** access it in the constructor.  Each function in the Controller that needs to use this data will need a parameter created for it.  Like this:

```
/**
 * The $subdomain variable below will capture the data stored in  
 * {account} in your route group.  Note that you can name this variable 
 * anything you'd like.
 */
public function showCreateBankAccount($subdomain) { 

   echo "This is your subdomain: " . $subdomain;

}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem though. Please see the EDIT 2 to my original question.

Comment: If you look at Antonio's answer above, I would like to do what he has done, except pass the `$domain` variable to a controller, instead of the closure function he has used.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now.  I do something similar when configuring data between environments.  Have you considered creating new variables in your configuration files and then simply calling them throughout your application using ''Config::get('app.variable_name')?

Comment: I didn't know about configuration files! Thank you. Perfect.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use just about any configuration file you'd like to store your variables.  To reference the file you've selected, simply replace the "app" in my "app.variable_name" example with, for instance, "database.variable_name" if you use the database config file.